# Submitting the form with subsequent replacement value

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

The problem is that when you first click changes `value` to `add` to `delete` but the form not sent when re-clicking on `add` `value` change and the form is submitted to `add`.

How to do ? Click > Send > Replacement

**form**

```
<form id="favorite" method="GET" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="iframe">
    <input type="submit" id="fav" name="favorite" value="add"/>
</form>
```

**js**

```
$(function(){$('#fav').click(
    function() {
        $(this).val() == "add" ? delete_item() : add_item();
    });
});
function delete_item() {
    $('#fav').val("delete");
}
function add_item() {
    $('#fav').val("add");
}
```

Comment: It work in this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3pfzyhe5/ if you add `<iframe name="iframe"></iframe>`

Comment: and so via an iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ganov/y7fwej75/) to show you how i would do it ...

### Html

```
<div id="MyForm">
  <form id="favorite" method="GET" action="" 
        enctype="multipart/form-data" target="iframe">
    <input type="submit" id="fav" name="favorite" value="add" />
  </form>
</div>
```

### Js

```
    $(function() {
      $("#MyForm").on('click', '#fav', function() {
        $(this).val() == "add" ? delete_item() : add_item();
        console.dir($(this));
        return false;
      });
    });

    function delete_item() {
      $('#fav').val("delete");
    }

    function add_item() {
      $('#fav').val("add");
    }
```

1. *I put a `return false;` so the form'll not be submited in my example, you should remove it to use the code.*
2. *I put a container div to use `$.on()` properly*
3. *I put a `console.dir` so you can debug it, you could remove it to use the code.*